# How to get a random letter from a list of specific letters?

Tags: java, random, letter

I've started writing some JAVA code and now I want to get a random letter from list of letters given so what should I use for this.

Answer (score 6):

I'll take your question literally:

```
Random r = new Random(); // Keep this stored as a field
List<Character> l = ...; // initialize this somewhere
char c = l.get(r.nextInt(l.size()));
```

Depending on several factors (are the letters contiguous, are you resizing the list dynamically), you may be able to use an array, or may not need a collection.  See the [Random](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

Example:

```
Random r = new Random(); // Keep this stored as a field
List<Character> l = Arrays.asList('A', 'F', 'O', 'W', 'M', 'I', 'C', 'E');
char c = l.get(r.nextInt(l.size()));
```

Comment: I can't compile the code above can you give me a sample, for example random letter from A F O W M I C E

Comment: @Ivan You can't compile it because you need to initialize the list. After that, it will compile, so just add the characters that you want to the list.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should be instructive:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomLetter {
   static Random r = new Random();  
   static char pickRandom(char... letters) {
      return letters[r.nextInt(letters.length)];
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         System.out.print(pickRandom('A', 'F', 'O', 'W', 'M', 'I', 'C', 'E'));
      }
   }   
}
```

See also:

- [`java.util.Random`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)
- [Varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

---

If you want to do 3 letters at a time, then you can do something like this instead:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomLetter {
   static Random r = new Random();  
   static char pickRandom(char... letters) {
      return letters[r.nextInt(letters.length)];
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         System.out.println("" +
            pickRandom("ACEGIKMOQSUWY".toCharArray()) +
            pickRandom("BDFHJLNPRVXZ".toCharArray()) +
            pickRandom("ABCDEFGHJKLMOPQRSTVWXYZ".toCharArray())
         );
      }
   }   
}
```